# Which anime of a man who falls in love with a snake that represents Medusa?

Tags: story-identification, anime

A long time ago I remembered watching an old anime where a man went into a magical store and about an exotic snake. When he took the snake home it became a beautiful lady that was blindfolded that represented as Medusa. They both fell in love and later the man tried removing her blindfolds and died because of it. The snake lady became depressed and ended her life by looking at her reflection. The anime ends with the police finding the man and snake dead with the snake eating its own tail.

Comment: There's a lot of good plot detail in here, but do you think you could add just how long ago you saw it (even if you give a decade or range of years it could have been),  as well as maybe which channel you saw it on as well as absolutely anything else you can think of :) The more useful details you add the more likely it is someone can a) remember it or b) find it out for you

Answer (score 3):

I remember this anime. It is about a shop—a pet shop actually. Almost everything they sell is an unusual animal. It's called **Pet Shop of Horrors**.

[Episode 3 synopsis](http://animangacorner.blogspot.com/2007/10/pet-shop-of-horrors.html?m=1):

> Robin Hendricks is an actor, after the phenomenal success of his debut movie, Robin couldn't get any more acting jobs. His wife had left him and his acting career was going nowhere because he had been typecast. Then, he was found dead in his apartment. The detective Leon immediately suspects the Count in the crime. A sugary treat convinces the Count to be talkative, and he tells Leon that the life of Robin was a lonely one and all he had was his collection of exotic lizards. On a visit to the pet shop to pick up an additional pet to cheer himself up, Count D shows something special to Robin. It is a very rare species of reptile known as Medusa, with the face and upper body of a beautiful woman, but the lower half of a large lizard. The condition is Robin could never look into Medusa's eyes, so Medusa lizard must always wear a blindfold, for her gaze could kill. Inspired by his new creature, Robin gives his all at his next audition so he can once again feel the adoration of the fans. But sometimes that just isn't enough and he realized that the only one can give him true love is his new pet. Too bad for him because the gaze of his pet lover's eyes will turn him to stone. And it happened.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain a bit about how this matches?  Is there a medusa snake in it?